# deadlock in Spring web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thread-safety

How to write thread safe Spring web application?

When we send 250 request at a time dead lock happening. How to solve this issue?

1.Controller - This controller receives the requests from the caller.
               When all 250 threads hit simultaneously.

```
public class TestController extends MultiActionController {

    private SyncService synchronizationService;
    public void setSynchronizationService(SyncService synchronizationService) {
        this.synchronizationService = synchronizationService;
    }
    public void StoreData(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    byte[] syncData = null;
        byte[] returnValue = null;
        try {
    syncData = readData(request);
            returnValue = synchronizationService.receiveData(syncData);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

2.Helper - This parses the input and populates a table.

```
        public class TestImpl implements SyncService {
    private DataParser dataParser = null;
    private QueueHelper queueHelper = null;

    public void setDataParser(DataParser dataParser) {
        this.dataParser = dataParser;
    }

   public void setQueueHelper(QueueHelper queueHelper) {
        this.queueHelper = queueHelper;
    }

 public byte[] receiveData(byte[] data) throws HibernateException, NumberFormatException {
        boolean addTransInQueue = false;
        String dataString = null;
        HashMap syncHashMap = null;
        try {

           InSyncModel syncModel = dataParser.parseData(dataString);
           addTransInQueue = queueHelper.addTransInQueue(syncModel, data);
           return "Succ".getBytes();
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException jse) {
              throw jse;
        }

    }
}
```

3.Configurations - The bean injections used for the above code.

```
   <bean name="synchronizationController" scope="request" class="TestController">
            <property name="synchronizationService" ref="synchronizationService"/>
   </bean>
     <bean name="synchronizationService" scope="request" class="TestImpl">
     <property name="dataParser" ref="dataParserObj"></property>
     <property name="queueHelper" ref="queueHelperObj"></property>
     </bean>


     <bean name="dataParserObj"  scope="request" class="DataParser"/>
     <bean name="queueHelperObj"  scope="request" class="QueueHelper">   
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

     </bean>
     </beans>
```

Answer (score 3):

> How to solve this issue?

By identifying where the deadlock is. This likely won't be a Spring issue, but rather a deadlock within your code somewhere.

Here's [how to generate a thread dump](http://expertodev.wordpress.com/2009/05/30/how-to-take-java-thread-dump/). The JVM thread dump will highlight which objects are deadlocked.

Comment: ? I'm sorry ? The above is a little confusing ?

Comment: @BrianAgnew Not confusing at all; just check his code. Sure, sure, I know what you're thinking... "Code?" Use magic.

Comment: Did you generate a thread dump ? What did it say ? Are you getting *any* exceptions, btw (you're catching and disposing of an exception in your code sample above!)

Comment: I am running this project in netbeans with tomcat. Please tell me how to check thread dump.

Comment: And also I dint get any exception in catch block. Tomcat simply hanging

Comment: post QueueHelper and DataParser and InSyncModel